# No me ingresa los valores a la DB

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

Tengo un formulario en **HTML** pero no me ingresa los datos a la *Base de Datos* que estoy haciendo mal.

```
        <?php
    session_start();
    if (!isset($_SESSION['user_login_status']) AND $_SESSION['user_login_status'] != 1) {
        header("location: login.php");
        exit;
        }
    /* Connect To Database*/
    require_once ("config/db.php");//Contiene las variables de configuracion para conectar a la base de datos
    require_once ("config/conexion.php");//Contiene funcion que conecta a la base de datos
    $title="Help desk";
           ?>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <?php include("head.php");?>
  </head>
  <body>
  <?php
    include("navbarhelpu.php");
    ?>
    <p><br>
    <form action="incidencias.php">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-danger">
    <div class="panel-heading" style="color:black;">
      <h2 style="font-size:130%;"><b> <Datos del usuario</b></h2>
    <Detalles de la cuenta
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
    <Nombre Funcionario:<strong> <?php  echo  $_SESSION['firstname'];?></strong>
                                 <br> <br> <Tipo de usuario: <strong> <?php  echo  $_SESSION['user_permision'];?></strong> 
    </div>
    </div>

        <div class="panel panel-danger">
        <div class="panel-heading" style="color:black;">
        <h2 style="font-size:130%;"><b>Especifique su incidencia</b></h2>
        Elija la opcion que se adapte a su necesidad
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
        <select  class="form-control " id="topicId" name="option">
        <option value="incidencia" id="incidencia" disabled selected>Escoja su incidencia</option>

         <option value="1">Option 1</option>
         <option value="2">Option 2</option>
         <option value="3">Option 3</option>

         </select>
        </div>
      </div>
        <div class="panel panel-danger">
        <div class="panel-heading" style="color:black;">
        <h2  style="font-size:130%;"><b>Detalles del ticket</b></h2>
          Elija un tema y una descripcion para mejorar la atencion,sea lo mas especifico posible
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">

        Tema<p>
       <div class ="col-sm-8" > 
    <input  id="tema" class="form-control" title="Por favor completa este campo" style="width:1078px" placeholder="Tema" type="text" name="Tema" required>
        <p><p>
        </div>
        <br><br><br>
        Detalle del incidente<p>
        <div class="col-sm-12" >
         <textarea  class="form-control"  id="Detalle" name="Detalle" placeholder="Detalle" required></textarea>
        </div>
        <br><br><br><br>
        <form method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input value="imageni" id="imageni" type="file" name="imagen" value="seleccion"> 
</form>
     </div>
     </div>

     <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" style="width:150px; height:30px"align="left" id="guardar_datos" value="Subir incidencia">

     <div id="resultados"></div><!-- Carga los datos ajax -->
     <div class='outer_div'></div><!-- Carga los datos ajax -->

     </div>
     </form>
    </body>
    </div>

    </html>
    <script>
          $( "#guardar_ticket" ).submit(function( event ) {
             $('#guardar_datos').attr("disabled", true);

            var parametros = $(this).serialize();
             $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax/nuevo_ticket.php",
            data: parametros,
             beforeSend: function(objeto){
                $("#resultados_ajax").html("Mensaje: Cargando...");
              },
            success: function(datos){
            $("#resultados_ajax").html(datos);
            $('#guardar_datos').attr("disabled", false);
            load(1);
              }
                });
               event.preventDefault();
               })

                  $( "#editar_ticket" ).submit(function( event ) {
                  $('#actualizar_datos2').attr("disabled", true);

                  var parametros = $(this).serialize();
                 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax/editar_ticket.php",
            data: parametros,
             beforeSend: function(objeto){
                $("#resultados_ajax2").html("Mensaje: Cargando...");
              },
            success: function(datos){
            $("#resultados_ajax2").html(datos);
            $('#actualizar_datos2').attr("disabled", false);
            load(1);
          }
            });
           event.preventDefault();
         })

    function get_user_ID(ID){
        $("#user_ID_mod").val(ID);
    }

    function obtener_datos(ID){
            var incidencia = $("#incidencia"+Nticket).val();
            var tema = $("#Tema"+Nticket).val();
            var detalle = $("#detalle"+Nticket).val();
            var imageni = $("imageni"+Nticket).val();       
            $("#mod_Nticket").val(id);
            $("#incidencia").val(incidencia);
            $("#tema").val(tema);
            $("#detalle").val(detalle);
            $("#imageni").val(imageni);
            $("#entregado").val(entregado);
        }
</script>
```

el codigo que inserta en la base de datos

```
              <?php
              include('is_logged.php');
               if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.7', '<')) {
                exit("Sorry, Simple PHP Login does not run on a PHP version 
              smaller than 5.3.7 !");
               } else if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.5.0', '<')) {
             // if you are using PHP 5.3 or PHP 5.4 you have to include the 
             password_api_compatibility_library.php
                  // (this library adds the PHP 5.5 password hashing 
                 functions to older versions of PHP)

             }      
                if (empty($_POST['incidencia'])){
            $errors[] = "Por favor seleccione una incidencia";
            } elseif (empty($_POST['tema'])){
        $errors[] = "Tema vacío";
    }  elseif (empty($_POST['detalle'])) {
        $errors[] = "detalle vacío";
    } elseif (empty($_POST['imageni']) {
        $errors[] = "imagen vacía";
    }  elseif (
        !empty($_POST['incidencia'])
        && !empty($_POST['tema'])
        && !empty($_POST['detalle'])
        && !empty($_POST['imageni'])
    ) {
        require_once ("../config/db.php");//Contiene las variables de configuracion para conectar a la base de datos
        require_once ("../config/conexion.php");//Contiene funcion que conecta a la base de datos

            // escaping, additionally removing everything that could be (html/javascript-) code
            $incidencia = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["incidencia"],ENT_QUOTES)));
            $tema = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["tema"],ENT_QUOTES)));
            $detalle = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["detalle"],ENT_QUOTES)));
            $imageni = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["imageni"],ENT_QUOTES)));
            // crypt the user's password with PHP 5.5's password_hash() function, results in a 60 character
            // hash string. the PASSWORD_DEFAULT constant is defined by the PHP 5.5, or if you are using
            // PHP 5.3/5.4, by the password hashing compatibility library
            // check if user or email address already exists
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM ticket WHERE incidencia = '" . $incidencia . "' OR tema = '" . $tema . "';";
            $query_check_incidencia = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

                $sql = "INSERT INTO ticket (incidencia, tema, detalle, imageni)
                        VALUES('".$incidencia."','".$tema."','" . $detalle . "', '" . $imageni . "');";
                $query_new_incidencia_insert = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

                // if user has been added successfully
                if ($query_new_ticket_insert) {
                    $messages[] = "La cuenta ha sido creada con éxito.";
                } else {
                    $errors[] = "Lo sentimos , el registro falló. Por favor, regrese y vuelva a intentarlo.";
                }
            }

    } else {
        $errors[] = "Un error desconocido ocurrió.";
    }

    if (isset($errors)){

        ?>
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                <strong>Error!</strong> 
                <?php
                    foreach ($errors as $error) {
                            echo $error;
                        }
                    ?>
        </div>
        <?php
        }
        if (isset($messages)){

            ?>
            <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                    <strong>¡Bien hecho!</strong>
                    <?php
                        foreach ($messages as $message) {
                                echo $message;
                            }
                        ?>
            </div>
            <?php
        }

     ?>
```

Comment: ayuda por favorr

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Ayuda no ingresan los datos en la BD](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/105585/ayuda-no-ingresan-los-datos-en-la-bd)

Comment: Tu pregunta está incompleta, sólo muestras la parte que envía la parte al servidor, pero ¿dónde está el código que inserta en la base de datos? ¿qué mensajes de error recibes?

Comment: no recibo mensaje de error solo no me ingresa

Comment: La función `submit()` se utiliza para elementos `form` y no para botones como lo estás haciendo.

Comment: ahhh y entonces como lo haria

Comment: Cambia el id `guardar_datos` al form y con eso ya podrás capturar tu evento de submit y el código JS se ejecutará

Comment: Al form tendrias que ponerle un id="guardar_ticket"

Comment: gracias voy a probar aver

Comment: no funciono incluso cambiandole el id tendira que ponelo aqui o en el submit  <form action="incidencias.php">
 <div class="container">
 <div class="panel panel-danger">

Comment: Aclarame algo: $( "#guardar_ticket" ).submit(function( event ) es para agregar ticket? otra: url: "ajax/nuevo_ticket.php", mandas ese form que esta arriba?  otra:= <form action="incidencias.php"> que hace incidencias.php, creo que tu error esta alli, ya que no se a donde lo quieres enviar para tratarlo

Comment: incidencias.php deberia mostrar los tickets que  ha hecho esa perona de acuerdo con lo ingresado en la DB y el #guardar_ manda ticket al ajax de nuevo usuario que esta en la parte superior ya puesto en la preguta

Answer (score 0):

Estás confundiendo la variable `$query_new_ticket_insert` con `$query_new_incidencia_insert`. Asegurate de usar un nombre consistente